# For every irrational $r$ does there exist a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ that converges to $r$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, how can I construct a sequence $(x_n)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=r$?

I don't want a specific example of an irrational number such as $e$ where $e=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n$ with $x_n=(1+1/n)^n$, but rather I want a generalization (if there is any).

Comment: Truncate the decimal expansion?

Comment: Or successive continued fraction approximations

Comment: How do I truncate the decimal expansion of $\pi$? Is there a theorem somewhere which says every irrational number has a rational expansion?

Comment: @sid yes, there's a theorem that says that every real number $r$ can be represented as $r = k + \sum_{i=1}^\infty d_i10^{-i}$ where $d_i\in\{0,1,…, 9\}$ and $k$ is an integer.  For example see section 1.22 in Rudin _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_ (p.11).

Comment: This one of my favorite exercise. the answer bellow give and explicit sequencce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb Q$ is dense everywhere. It implies that for every $\varepsilon >0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$, there are infinitely many rationals in the interval $(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)$.

So we obtain a sequence by fixing for every $n\in\mathbb N$ an element $x_n\in (x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n})\cap\mathbb Q$.

Put simply, for every $n\in\mathbb N$ we "pick" an element $x_n\in\mathbb Q$ whose distance from $x$ is less than $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

From lulu's comment, consider the sequence
$$x_n=\frac{\lfloor r\cdot 10^n\rfloor}{10^n}\quad \mbox{for $n\geq 0$}$$

Comment: But wouldn't the $10^n$ cancel out, so that $x_n=r$ is irrational?

Comment: @sid: $\lfloor\ldots\rfloor$ means that you throw away the fraction part of the argument.  So for example $\frac{\lfloor\pi\cdot 10^4\rfloor}{10^4} = \frac{\lfloor 31415.926…\rfloor}{10^4} = \frac{31415}{10^4} = 3.1415$ exactly.  Note that the $10^4$s did not cancel out.

Comment: @SidCaroline $\lfloor\ldots\rfloor$ is the socalled floor function. Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$\lfloor 2^nr\rfloor \le 2^nr <  \lfloor 2^nr\rfloor +1\Longleftrightarrow  \frac{\lfloor 2^nr\rfloor}{2^n}\rfloor \le r \le  \frac{\lfloor 2^nr\rfloor}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^n}\Longleftrightarrow  0\le r-\frac{\lfloor 2^nr\rfloor}{2^n}\le  \frac{1}{2^n}\to 0$$

That is $$\frac{\lfloor 2^nr\rfloor}{2^n}\to r,~~~\forall r\in\mathbb R$$
 but $$\lfloor 2^nr\rfloor \in\mathbb Z,~~~\forall r\in\mathbb R,\forall n\in\mathbb N $$
ie

$$\frac{\lfloor 2^nr\rfloor}{2^n}\in \mathbb Q~~~\forall r\in\mathbb R,\forall n\in\mathbb N $$